# AWS Lambda S3 'x-amz-version-id' Not Included in Metadata

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have the following code:

```
import json
import requests
import boto3
import os
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('Received event:' + str(event))
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    S3Client = boto3.client('s3','us-east-1')
    url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/%s" % (bucket, key)
    ID_Resp = S3Client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    print(ID_Resp)
    version_id = ID_Resp['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['x-amz-version-id']
```

Where I'm receiving an S3 object from a bucket on Object Create. Ultimately I want to POST metadata about the file to a custom API. I'm trying to call the `head_object` method so I can get the `x-amz-version-id` so I know what version of the file was submitted to the API. When I run the last line on my local machine, it works, but when I run it from within the lambda environment, the key value pair for `x-amz-version-id` is missing altogether. Does anyone know why this might be? Cant find anything in the docs about it.

Comment: Make sure the lambda has the correct IAM Role assigned so that it can access that bucket

Comment: @JohnB it does, to test I gave it Admin Access and it still doesn't appear